# How to export/upload an html/javascript blob file to the client PC displaying the html file?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, blob

I wrote a c++/c# Windows program that creates an html report using an xsl transform. The html report includes canvas element drawings. I give the user the option of converting the html report to a Word doc (if it's installed), but, although the conversion works fine, it ignores the canvas drawings. As a workaround, I would like to convert the canvas elements to png images and "export" them to the client PC (that is using my program to create the report). I know how to convert the canvas to a dataURL and then to a blob, but I can't figure out how to upload the blob file to the client PC, which of course is not a webserver.
Also, once the file is on the client, can the blob be treated as a png image?

Comment: It is not necessary to convert `data URI` to `Blob`. You can use `download` attribute at `<a>` element with `.href` property set to `data URI` or `Blob URL` to offer user file for download.

Answer (score 0):

### [Edit] : I missed that the export is made to an *.doc* file

---

In this case, it depends on how you are converting your html to *.doc*.

- In the case of an *.docx*, it should be possible to include your canvas' images as attachments in the *.docx* internal file tree, under *word > media*.
- In the case of an *.doc*, the image file seems to be merged into the *.doc* file itself, might be possible to use an FileReader to append it.
- If you are using a library, it depends on the library you use. The first one I found on google ([html-docx-js](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js)), claims that they need your images as dataURI to be able to save it.

And to convert all your canvases to dataURI, you can use something along the lines of :

```
document.querySelectorAll('canvas').forEach( canvas =>{
  var img = new Image();
  try{
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    canvas.replaceWith(img);
    }
  catch(e){
    handleTaintedCanvas(); // I let you decide what should happen here
    }
  });
```

So once it's done, you would just have to call this lib, and it should work.

---

---

### [Previous] This answers how to export to an stand-alone *.html* file.

For better compatibility across devices, convert your canvases to dataURI png images.

---

#### The Blob way

If you want to go the Blob way, you'd have to save a folder, containing your html file, and all the images as separated files, with correct references to them in the HTML markup.

That's possible too, e.g you could generate an zip file with the correct structure, and all included files, but some browsers don't accept loading external files from the `file://` protocol, and your user would have to keep the directory structure untouched.

So all in all,

- a lot of work for you,
- little advantages (37% of image files size...)
- complications for your users (all don't even know what to do with an zip file...)

---

#### `<canvas>` to dataURL

To convert your canvases to dataURI, a simple function would be

*[Moved to edit]*

And from now on, all your *clean* canvases will be converted to dataURI images, that you'll be able to export with your html file, which will be standalone.

---

#### `<script>` to dataURL

Note that there is also an third way to handle it (could be the best one actually depending on the nature of your original page):

You can convert all your `<script>` tags to dataURI, and keep your canvases in the document. This way, you'll still have an standalone working html file. But this implies that you don't need external resources.

Comment: The canvas to dataURL is a good way to go. I'll just have to add "download/export" buttons to each canvas and let the user manually download the images that they can then insert into the generated Word doc. I did not understand Kaiido's <script> to dataURL suggestion.

Comment: @Paul.B, I somehow missed that you do export to Word's .doc file... sorry, I though you did export to standalone .html file, in which case, converting the <script> tags to dataURL and keeping the `<canvas>` elements would have been the best solution. But now that I see it, this part and most of my answer is completely off. My bad, I will edit soon.

Comment: Thanks, Kaiido. Using your example code to convert the canvas elements to dataURI and then the javascript routines from html-docx-js [link](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js) is a good solution and works great.